# Nexus 5 not recognized at all by device manager

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I've been programming a game for android and been using my nexus 5 for debugging purposes for a while. Unfortunately, today it isnt being recognized anymore.

Things I've tried to fix it:

- Enabled USB debugging
- Tried another cable
- Unplugged replugged
- restarted android studio
- restarted laptop
- Switched to MTP
- Switched to PTP
- Factory reset device
- killed adb server then started it again

Since it doesnt come up on the device manager at all - I was unable to reinstall drivers.

I've been trying to fix this for about 4 hours now and I'm starting to go crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get the notification that the phone is connected?

Comment: The only form of notification I get is that it's charging.

Comment: Use a different USB port or PC?

Comment: I tried my nexus 7 and that one works. I think there might be something wrong with my nexus 5.